# How to disable remaining checkboxes after checking some of them

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the remaining uncheck box when I check some of them. That means if I check any two boxes and get its value then the other left uncheck box will become disable. I have made a function to get the result but I am getting this that if I check one box then all the boxes become disable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demoo">How would you like your coffee?</p>

<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="100">With cream<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="150">With sugar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="200">With milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="250">With tea<br>
<br>
<input type="button"  value="Send order">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
<input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
  var coffee = document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]"); // To get arrays by Attribute in query selector use [] to get arrays of the same attribute. We can also use ("input[type = checkbox]") to get arrays.
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
   if (coffee[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + coffee[i].value + ", ";
      document.getElementById("order2").value = "You ordered a coffee with: " + txt.slice(0, -2);

    }

    if (coffee.length = 1) {

     document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = i;
     document.getElementById("order3").value = "Boxes left uncheck " + i;
     coffee[i].setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5");
    }
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<input type="checkbox">` with radio buttons:

```html
<input type="radio" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="100">With cream<br>
<input type="radio" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="150">With sugar<br>
<input type="radio" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="200">With milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="250">With tea<br>

<script>
// ignore the code below: just so that stackoverflow dont throw errors on this snipet
function myFunction2() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. You can use a few css selectors and a loop here. See snippet (and comments)

```js
// add a click handler to all clicks in the document
document.addEventListener(`click`, checkTheBoxes);

function checkTheBoxes(evt) {
  // don't do anything if the click was not on one of the checkboxes
  if (evt.target.name !== `coffee`) { return true; }
  
  // get all checked checkboxes using the css selector
  // "[name = coffee]:checked"
  const coffee = document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked");

  // if 2 checkboxes are checked, disable the other two, 
  // using selector "[name = coffee]:not(:checked)")
  if (coffee.length === 2) {
    // [...[...]] 'spreads' the found elements into an Array 
    // which enables the use of 'forEach' on it.
    [...document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:not(:checked)")]
      .forEach(cb => cb.disabled = true);
  } else {
    // enable if length !== 2
    [...document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:not(:checked)")]
      .forEach(cb => cb.disabled = false);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demoo">How would you like your coffee?</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
<br>
<button >Send order</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, just add your desired condition in for loop.

You can give checkBoxes an id, then get those checkboxes by id and set them to false like below,

```
document.getElementById("myCheck0").disabled = true;
```

for multiple we can set id: "MyCheck0" and then run for loop like this:

```
function disableAllMyCheck() {
  for(i = 0; document.getElementById("MyCheck" + i) !== null; i++) {
    document.getElementById("MyCheck" + i).disabled = true;
}
}
```

Comment: this way you'd have to disable them 1 by 1 and not "remaining checkboxes".

Comment: You can run for loop against them.

Comment: @samura now you can add your desired condition in for loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function myFunction2() {
      var coffee  = document.getElementsByName('coffee');
      var checked = [];
      var maxChecked = 2;
      
      // Order info
      var order2 = document.getElementById("order2");
      order2.value = "You ordered a coffee with: ";
      
      // Loop all the checkboxes
      for (var i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {
        var chk = coffee[i];
        if (chk.checked) {
          // Add to checked
          checked.push(chk);
          
          // Add order info to the input
          order2.value += chk.value;
          if (checked.length < maxChecked) {
            // Add a comma except for last element
            order2.value += ", ";
          }
        }
        if (checked.length == maxChecked) {
          // Disable all and stop looping
          coffee.forEach(e => e.disabled = true);
          break;
        }
      }

      // Unchecked boxes info
      var order3 = document.getElementById("order3");
      order3.value = "Boxes left uncheck " + (coffee.length - checked.length);
    }
```

```html
    <p id="demoo">How would you like your coffee?</p>

    <form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="100">With cream<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="150">With sugar<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="200">With milk<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" onclick="myFunction2()" value="250">With tea<br>
      <br>
      <input type="button"  value="Send order">
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="order2" size="50">
      <input type="text" id="order3" size="50">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I hope this is more or less what you were trying to implement.